# Access webservices deployed on a local jboss server from bb simulator

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I have deployed a webservice on my local jboss server which runs on port 9090. So my webservice url will be http://localhost:9090/app/Services/blah. I have written a mobile client code(for blackberry) which connects to this url to get the data. Initially the client code when run on a bb simulator threw HTTP 403 error. Found that addressing urls as localhost won't work on a bb simulator ( on a simualtor localhost refers to the MDS? ).

So I tried accessing the local jboss server using http://127.0.0.1:9090 , http://machinename:9090/, http://ipaddress:9090 and nothing works. All these urls throw HTTP 501(Service unavailable) which is weird. Can someone tell me what is wrong with this and what is the correct way to access the server?

http://machinename:9090/, http://ipaddress:9090 -> These urls are not even working when i try directly on a desktop browser. FYI, its a windows machine. Do I have to change any nw settings on my machine.?

Answer (score 0):

chedine,
I am not good at bb. But, can you please ensure that your App Server is up & running? Can you access the JMX-Console screen of JBoss in your desktop browser - ie. http://a.b.c.d:9090/jmx-console or something similar. Only if the app server is up, we can dig further into this issue. Please let us know the result.

Comment: Ofcourse it is up and running. localhost:9090/mywebserviceurl works fine on my desktop browser.